# Thread safe counter c++11

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I am trying to implement a `int` counter which is always incremented by one thread `(Thread1)` and always decremented by another `(Thread2)`.

one option is to use `std::atomic<int>`.

Although i got another idea where i have two variables say `counterIncr` and `counterDecr`.
`Thread1` always increments `counterIncr`, while Thread2 always decrements `counterDecr`.

And I will use the sum of `(counterIncr+counterDecr)` as my final result.

Does this have any performance advantage? Is this wait-free?

Comment: It's usually better to have threads use resources that aren't shared.  But when will you take the sum?  After the threads end?

Comment: depends on when and where the final result is computed

Comment: Hi Anon, The sum will always be used by `Thread1`

Comment: @ashwin929 `(counterIncr+counterDecr)` How should this be better? You'll still need to lock to get correct results from the calculation.

Comment: well than there might be a dirty read on `counterDecr`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ its better since it only needs a lock at the time of final result.. but using atom the lock is juggled around.. every time a thread modifies the `atomic` it has to acquire a lock on it.. and the other the same, so entering and exiting the critical section every now and then might not be a not so good idea

Comment: @Minato Well, that's a fair point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need a result that is accessible at any time, using `std::atomic` is the correct thing to do, and if "just a counter" is all you need, `std::memory_order_relaxed` is sufficient, which is reasonably efficient.
Do however note that you still have *significant* bus overhead, so if you do millions of increments, this may become a limiting factor. Do not do this unless you only expect a few hundred or so increments total (in that case it doesn't matter), or unless you *really* need to be able to read the value any time.

If you need a *final* result after doing many calculations, it is much, much preferrable to join the two threads (or block them, or signal the main thread that you are done and no longer writing to the counters) and have each thread update only a per-thread counter *non-atomically*. You can use a reference or a per-reference lambda capture so the consuming thread has "easy" access to the result.
This will not hammer the bus and will run a lot faster, but of course you only have a valid result available at the end, not any time before that.

Comment: Thanks, I do need to acces the value at any time, and unfortunately the counter may easily be in the order of millions. So i guess using `std::atomic` is the way to go.